# NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, rest, iteraciones, pipe

Buenos días, soy nuevo en Angular2 y tengo ciertos problemas con el uso de los Observables y componentes

**ERROR a solucionar**

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tengo un servicio REST que me devuelve un JSON con cierta información,Desde el componente que he creado, llamo a dicho servicio:

**Componente.ts**

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.getSystems();
  }

  getSystems(): void {
    this.systemService.getSystems()
    .subscribe(systems => this.systems = systems);
  }
```

El problema es que no trato con un Array de información, sino con un objeto, por lo que **no puedo usar el comando *ngfor**

**Componente.html**

```
 <li *ngFor="let system of systems">
    <a routerLink="/systemDetail/{{system.systemId}}">
        <span class="badge">{{system.systemId}}</span> 
        {{system.host}}
        {{system.password}}
        {{system.port}}
        {{system.rfcDest}}
        {{system.userId}}
        {{system.version}}
    </a>
  </li>
```

Según he leído, la solución sería crear un @Pipe pero no tengo claro como funciona. ¿Alguién podría aclararmelo?

**JSON**

```
{
    "test":
    [
        {
            "host": "h265",
            "messagingSystemID": "1",
            "password": "xxx,
            "port": "50000",
            "rfcDest": "testDes",
            "systemID": "PPO",
            "userId": "TestUser",
            "version": "7.5"
        },
        {
            "host": "h455",
            "messagingSystemID": "2",
            "password": "xxx",
            "port": "50000",
            "rfcDest": "testDes2",
            "systemID": "PPO",
            "userId": "TestUser",
            "version": "7.5"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Respuesta esperada**
Mi intención es imprimi dichos sistemas en formato texto, tabla, o de cualquier manera posible. Pero todos ellos.

**Service - Opción 1**
Esta es la primera solución que intenté realizar

```
   /** GET systems from the server */
  getSystems (): Observable<System[]> {
    var data = this.http.get<System[]>(this.systemsUrl);
    console.log('getSystems service');
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }
```

**Error mostrado**
[image: Error 1]

**Service - Solución 2**
También he probado a realizar la llamada del servicio de la siguiente manera:

```
   getSystems(): Observable<System[]> {
       let url = 'http://10.8.0.2:50000/integration.experts~web~mappingtesttool/rest/systems';
        console.log(url);
        return this.http.get(url)
          .map(this.extractData);
  }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
      let body = res.json();
      console.log("extraData");
      return body || { }; // here
    }
```

**Error mostrado**
[image: Error 2]

¿Alguno podría decirme en que estoy fallando? Me es indiferente usar la opción 1 o opción 2 del servicio. Saludos

Comment: agrega el error que te da, y el json que recibes

Comment: Listo, ya lo he añadido

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, creo que el problema está en que el mapeo de la respuesta no es totalmente correcto

Comment: con tu respuesta modificada , verifica la opcion de @PabloLozano cambia tu service por algo como `return this.http.get("tu_url")
        .map(res => res.json());` y en tu component algo como `tuServicio.getSystems().subscribe(data => this.extractData=  data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba a hacer este cambio:

```
getSystems(): Observable<System[]> {
   let url = 'http://localhost:50000/...';
    console.log(url);
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(this.extractData);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  console.log("extraData: ");
  if (body && body.test) {
    body=body.test;
  }
  return body || []; // devolvemos un array vacio si la respuesta no tiene un array
}
```

Explicación: La respuesta es un objeto de la forma

```
{
  "test": [ ... ]
}
```

Pero tú quieres el array de systems que viene dentro y que es iterable, no el objeto que lo contiene.

> Ten cuidado con las diferencias de [Angular 2 y Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45129790/5695795) con los HTTP

Comment: He cambiado totalmente la respuesta, mira a ver ahora

Comment: Hum, `this.http.get(...)` debería volver un Observable... tienes `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` al principio de tu fichero?

Comment: Es raro porque lo que estoy haciendo es prácticamente lo que tienes, pero extrayendo el array del objeto... si lo que tenías antes te funcionaba lo reescribiré a tu estilo a ver

Comment: Quizá fue una errata mía: res o resp hace referencia al objeto de clase Response (Respuesta)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68754/discussion-between-mario-lopez-batres-and-pablo-lozano).

Comment: @PabloLozano de igual forma en el html tienes que validar que no venga vacio no debiste quitarlo

Comment: En los ejemplos suelo usar la política de no añadir comprobaciones y asumir el caso ideal para no cargar el código, son "pruebas de concepto" que sirven como guía, pero tienes razón en que hacen falta comprobaciones.

Answer (score 1):

si te devuelve un objeto , normalmente te da error por que son procesos **Asincronos** cuando muestras el valor muestra que no existe, lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
<a routerLink="/systemDetail/{{system?.systemId}}">
    <span class="badge">{{system?.systemId}}</span> 
    {{system?.host}}
    {{system?.password}}
    {{system?.port}}
    {{system?.rfcDest}}
    {{system?.userId}}
    {{system?.version}}
</a>
```

puedes verificar mas en la [respuesta en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34911295/5695795)

> Una variacion de la respuesta de [@Pablo Lozano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/117021/28035)